# obtaining the percentage of a repeated non zero values

Tags: r

my data is like this

```
df<-structure(list(team_3_F = c("browingal ", "browingal ", "browingal ", 
"browingal ", "browingal ", "browingal ", "browingal ", "browingal ", 
"browingal ", "browingal ", "browingal ", "browingal ", "newyorkish", 
"newyorkish", "newyorkish", "newyorkish", "site", "site", "site", 
"site", "site", "site", "team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", 
"team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", 
"team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", 
"team ", "team ", "team "), AAA_US = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 88L, 5L, 11L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 45L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 19L), BBB_US = c(0L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 45L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 18L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 19L), CCC_US = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 88L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 19L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-44L))
```

I want to obtain the the percentage of each combinations in regards to each category for instance

```
   AAA_BBB_US   AAA_CCC_US      
    2              1               12   browingal 
    2              2                4   newyorkish
    0              0                6   site
    4              2               22   team
```

which means it will be the following percentage

```
AAA_BBB_US                     AAA_CCC_US       
    2/12*100               1/12*100           
    2/4*100                2/4*100             
    0/6*100                0/6*100              
    4/22*100               2/22*100
```

so the output will be like this

```
AAA_BBB_US    AAA_CCC_US
16%            8.3%
50%            50%
0%             0%
18%            9%
```

Comment: I can't replicate your output for `newyorkish`, please check below. If I've misunderstood what you want to do here, my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your AAA_BBB_US, AAA_CCC_US and AAA_BBB_CCC_US columns as below (i.e. will be `TRUE` if the product is non-zero, then, by team sum the values, dividing by the number of rows (`n()`) in each group

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(AAA_BBB_US = AAA_US*BBB_US!=0,
         AAA_CCC_US = AAA_US*CCC_US!=0,
         AAA_BBB_CCC_US = AAA_US*BBB_US*CCC_US!=0)%>% 
  group_by(team_3_F) %>%
  summarize(across(AAA_BBB_US:AAA_BBB_CCC_US, ~sum(.x)/n()))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  team_3_F     AAA_BBB_US AAA_CCC_US AAA_BBB_CCC_US
  <chr>             <dbl>      <dbl>          <dbl>
1 "browingal "      0.167     0.0833         0.0833
2 "newyorkish"      0.25      1              0.25  
3 "site"            0         0              0     
4 "team "           0.182     0.0909         0.0909
```

Comment: @langtang this is for sure great, can you also add the 3 combinations too? AAA_BBB_CCC_US?

Comment: sure, something like the above edit?